# CRC32 calculation doesn't match default one

Tags: java, groovy, crc32

I'm writing a program to compute CRC32 in Groovy. For some reason I don't get expected value (same as if I used `java.util.zip` implementation):

```
def crc32(byte[] bytes) {
    return new java.util.zip.CRC32().with { update bytes; value }
}

def myCrc32(byte[] bytes) {
    def remainder = 0x0
    def multiple = 0
    def poly = 0xEDB88320   

    bytes.each { b ->
        remainder ^= b
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
             multiple = (remainder & 1) ? poly : 0;
             remainder = (remainder >> 1) ^ multiple;
        }
    }
    return remainder
 }


def origFile = 'file'
def fileBytes = new File(origFile).text.getBytes()
def origRes = crc32(fileBytes)
def myRes = myCrc32(fileBytes)

println origRes
println myRes
```

Where did I do a mistake? I used the following sources as guide:

- http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/crc32.txt

Results that I get:

```
1838399800 - original
4005013284 - my calculation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured this out myself.

1)As base `remainder` `java.util.zip.Crc32` uses 0xFFFFFFF.

2)Library actually flips bits before giving an answer by XORing with `0xFFFFFFF`. So basically I added the same XOR to the `return` statement and got right answer.